# How to get the UNC path of a file hosted on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, tableau-api, unc

I have the drive mapped to my PC, which is no good.

I need to find the UNC path of the excel/csv files. The use case if for linking with Tableau.

I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers in this SO post, you can check some answers there.

But of all, here is the quickest:

> Maybe a long way around but open a cmd window. Then do net use >
>   filename
>
> Then open the filename and you can get the path:
>   Ex:
>
> `C:\Users\me\net use > drives.txt`
>
> Opening `drives.txt`
>
> ```
> New connections will be remembered.
> Status       Local     Remote                    Network
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>              H:        \\server\c\proj\net       Microsoft Windows Network
> ```
>
> Can copy `\\server\c\prog\net` from the file for your use.
>
> Hope this helps.

You also have another choice, [convert shared folder path to UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722852/convert-shared-folder-path-to-unc-path).