# How to get a UNC path from Application.Path?

Tags: vba

I want to get the path of the active workbook in vba code.
`ActiveWorkbook.Path` does this

BUT

I need it to retrieve something like this:

```
\\MachineName\ShareFolder\ETC\ETC2
```

NOT:

```
S:\ETC\ETC2
```

Where `S:` maps to `\\MachineName\ShareFolder\`. How would I do that?

Comment: Please show us your current code

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question may be short, but it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir OP is using `Application.Path` and getting a mapped network drive but needs a UNC path, which part is unclear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Shared folder path to UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722852/convert-shared-folder-path-to-unc-path)

Answer (score 4):

```
    Dim Drive As String
    Drive = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 2)

    ActiveWorkbookPath = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Path, Drive, GetNetworkPath(Drive))


Function GetNetworkPath(ByVal DriveName As String) As String

    Dim objNtWork  As Object
    Dim objDrives  As Object
    Dim lngLoop    As Long


    Set objNtWork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set objDrives = objNtWork.enumnetworkdrives

    For lngLoop = 0 To objDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        If UCase(objDrives.Item(lngLoop)) = UCase(DriveName) Then
            GetNetworkPath = objDrives.Item(lngLoop + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to convert the filepath or any junk like that, try out a couple of the other properties that the `Workbook` object offers. I personally use `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` with all of my projects (which are hosted on network drives) and I have never had an issue.

That said, if this approach doesn't work then there are certainly ways of converting the filepath. While I prefer going through the properties of objects first (they tend to be more reliable), I am not resistant to using a function to solve the problem. That's where checking out this article: https://pagecommunication.co.uk/2014/07/15/vba-to-convert-a-mapped-drive-letter-to-unc-path/ and checking this answer [Convert Shared folder path to UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722852/convert-shared-folder-path-to-unc-path) might help. The only difference between both is that the former requires a reference to Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime, the other does not.

Comment: I don't know how it is in older versions but in Office 2010 `ThisWorkbook.FullName` uses the mapped drive rather than the UNC. I went through the available variables without a success in finding anything ready to use. So the question is really valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub yourSub()
 strMyFullPath = ConvertToFullPath("S:\ETC\ETC2") 'Call below sub
End Sub

Sub ConvertToFullPath(strShortPath as string) as string

 Dim obj1 as object
 Set obj1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 c = obj1.GetDriveName(strShortPath)
 a = obj1.GetDrive(c).ShareName
 
 strFullPath = Replace(strShortPath,c,a)
 
 ConvertToFullPath = strFullPath

End Sub
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: It works well. I had to change the declaration ConvertToFullPath from Sub to Function because it is returning a value. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The code below will identify the filepath in the manner you requested.

```
Path = Right(CurDir(), Len(CurDir()) - InStr(CurDir(), "\") + 1)
```

Comment: You missed the part where `S:` actually means `\\MachineName\ShareFolder\ ` and thus, your code won't solve the problem. Sure, it will remove the `S:`. But that could be done with `Path = Replace(Path, "S:", vbNullString)`.

Comment: replace only works if you know the letter of the drive, now check it

Comment: Don't forget code formatting. Still though, all you are doing is removing the drive letter, not converting it. You could of course then append the proper mapping to the path and get what you need, but that is a very roundabout approach for something so darned simple. Plus, that would break easier than a piece of fine china. As soon as `...\ShareFolder\ ` changes to `..\SharedFolder\ ` or ..\Foo\ ` or `..\Bar\ ` your approach breaks. Dont rely on hardcoded replacement, and don't hack off the drive mapping just because you havent found the right way yet.

Comment: FWIW, there is code, easily found on Google, that finds the mapping of a drive letter. But that still is not likely to be the best way.