# Invoke a hyperlink address in an Outlook email VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink, invoke

A common problem at work is that I use Ctrl + K to invite/insert a network link to a new email message.

Example:
L: \ Direktgeschaft \ Ajanlati_sablonok \ Angebot_muster.docx

I can only convert this by editing the link to the full hyperlink title or in an Excel worksheet with a macro. (Hyperlink.Range.Value = Hyperlink.Address in excel vba in a for each loop)

Converted to:
\\ Samplefilesrv \ SampleDokument \ Direktgeschaft \ Suggestions_templates \ Angebot_muster.docx

Is there a solution to this with an Outlook VBA macro that converts the network path to the full hyperlink address after inserting and selecting it in the new message window? This would be a much faster solution: convert with an Outlook macro in a new message than indirect editing, but unfortunately I can't solve it.

Thanks for the answers and help in advance too!

Comment: May be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908572/how-to-get-a-unc-path-from-application-path

Answer (score 0):

The message body represents a regular HTML web page. You can use the `HTMLBody` property which returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. You can paste a hyperlink programmatically between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags. For example:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

FYI The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word `Document` which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and information :)